# Matplotlib figure only shows after second file run

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, hydrogen

I am doing some basic plotting routine (as below), and after the first file run I will only get `<Figure size 640x460 with 1 Axes>` appearing in the output area. And then on the second run of the code, the figure will actually be plotted. Ideally it would plot on the first run, as later I want to test some matplotlib style editting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(20)
plt.plot(data  , label='1')
plt.plot(data+2, label='2')
plt.plot(data+4, label='3')
plt.plot(data+6, label='4')
plt.plot(data+8, label='5')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('X label')
plt.ylabel('Y label')
plt.show()
```

I'm using Python 3.6 in Hydrogen (Atom)

Comment: What happens if you run your original code from the command line, and not using hydrogen?    I just ran your code in python and in python3,   (console command in bash, #python yourcode.py and #python3 yourcode.py) , and it works the first time.

Comment: The reason is that some backend needs to be set. `matplotlib.use` does that. I don't know what hydrogen does, but maybe the default backend isn't suitable so you need to set one manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```

Solves the issue and plots first run (not sure why exactly)